# Looking for software: diff for video

Tags: video, diff, comparison

I’m looking for software that can identify the differences in scenes between two videos. That is, I’m interested in inserted or removed sections of a video. (Think “Which scenes does the director’s cut contain that aren’t in the standard release?”)

This could either be a standalone tool or a feature of a larger video editing app.

Comment: the `ffmpeg` command line tool should be able to do this. could be worth looking into

Comment: Thanks. I’ve looked both at the ffmpeg documentation and at Ffworks (a tool that is to a large degree a UI on top of ffmpeg) and neither does seem to offer this functionality. Maybe it is possible to program something similar with ffmpeg, but that’s not what I had in mind.

Comment: does this help? http://dericed.com/2012/display-video-difference-with-ffmpegs-overlay-filter/

Answer (score 1):

There's a project called [video-compare](https://github.com/pixop/video-compare) which is meant for videos with the *same* length/framecount. I played a role in writing its [Homebrew formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/video-compare#default), for simpler installation.

But I'm also eagerly looking for something more like what you describe: better at detecting removed/added *sequences*, closer to what text diffs do.